# Can update Elastic Beanstalk from Single instance to Load balancer,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I had one environment in the application. I decided to clone that environment(I wasn`t able to clone as environment has a Load balancer and I switched it back to a single instance ).
Now when I am trying to upgrade my environment to Load balancer all time I get an issue

> ERROR   Creating load balancer failed Reason: EC2-Classic load balancer port must be either 25, 80, 443, 465, 587 or 1024~65535 inclusive (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 5052aa7b-885c-47e6-8446-75990c9d9274)

This occurs for initial one and cloned one. 
Security group for the enviroment looks like

[image]

Anyone help me, what can be the issue?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you specified any subnet settings for the load balancer?

Comment: @RahulSharma you mean when I am changing type in elastic beanstalk configurations? But there no options for changing subnet settings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you still running your EB as a single instance? If you are try to add at least another instance. Second, if creating the Load Balancer through EB still throws an error, try creating a load balancer following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-application-load-balancer.html) and once you have configured a target group try to manually add the instances of your EB application (you can either look for the ID of the instance under your environment's **Health** tab or they should have the name of your environment in the "Register targets" step). Keep in mind that you must create the load balancer in the same VPC where your EB is deployed, and also to enable for your LB the same availability zones for which your EB application gets deployed. I hope this help you solve your problem